# In a huge project, how to determine whether a variable should be declared volatile?

Tags: java, netbeans, project-management, volatile

Say that I have taken over a rather big project, whose code hasn't been documented and thread-safety is practically non-existant. For the sake of the topic, let's assume that the project contains no less than **100,000 lines of code.**

How would I determine if a variable is being accessed by multiple threads? Can I determine all the variables that are? I'm trying to make all such variables `volatile`, but finding them all is... yeah.

Can Java find all such variables? I bet not - Then how about **netbeans?** Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How about "find references" ? Also, "making them all volatile" sounds like a very bad idea, but that's beside the question..

Comment: Marking the fields as `volatile` won't solve your problems, if any. I would not worry about this until a real thread-safety problem arise, evaluate how to reproduce the problem and then take actions to solve it.

Comment: It looks like are looking for a shotgun approach, but unfortunately there's only a surgical knife approach to threading :-(

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It would seem I have a lot to learn about threading still. I'll fix the problems when they arise, as usual, then.